# the segue action unwindFromChildView is not defined

Tags: swift, uistoryboard

I am working on somebody else's code and I'm trying to execute a few lines whenever the exit segue is performed, I connect the exit outlet of my viewcontroller in interface builder to the function unwindFromChildView which is in my .swift file but I receive the error :-
the segue action unwindFromChildView is not defined

Comment: Please, can you provide the source code for the `unwindFromChildView` method? This method should be declared in the destination view controller of the segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the signature of the unwindFromChildView func is correct, this is key on getting the unwind segues to work. iOS will look for that signature in the view controllers in your navigation stack, and will unwind the stack to the view controller that has that method.

```
-(IBAction)unwindFromChildView :(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
   // whatever
 }
```

Swift:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromChildView (segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    return
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: that does help thank you, it also made me realize that this is not the function I've been looking for, as I mentioned I'm working on someone else's abandoned project, the application displays some file directories using table view, and he traverses through these directories, I need to handle the event where the user clicks on the back button (in the top left of the screen) to go back one directory. I think a uinavigation item is used but I cant find any code related to that back button. I realize the question isnt clear but I'm very desperate for any guesses at this point. thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you need is the prepare for Segue method, which is called before a segue is triggered, try overriding that method and attach the debugger to find out when its called. 

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {...}

Then you should be able to do whatever logic you need when a specific segue is called. keep in mind that this method will be called for any segue in that View Controller, so you need to identify which segue is being called through the segue parameter.